# Connecting LED strips, Which plugs?

Tags: led

I want to make a LEDstrip(RGB, 300 LED, 3528, 5 meter) At the back of my 40 inch television.
But I have some struggles finding out what I need for that.

I have found this strip:
[LED Strip](http://www.miniinthebox.com/nl/5m-300x3528-smd-rgb-led-strip-licht-en-44key-afstandsbediening-en-3a-eu-voeding-110-240-v-wisselspanning_p2256324.html)

And I Found these connectors: [Ebay.com](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/3528-8mm-5050-10mm-T-L-X-Shape-Adapters-pcb-LED-Strip-Connectors-No-soldering-/151499152318?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&var=&hash=item23460d9bbe)

I can't seem to find any: 3825/8mm RGB plugs or anything like that.... But is it Universal? Some Ebay sellers say that it is for both, but I've also seen posts which say it doesn't match.

I hope someone can tell me if I can use the: 5050/10mm RGB connectors also for the 3528/8mm strip!

Comment: Just an FYI, but 5m and 300 LEDs is a little overkill to go behind your TV... Why not get a pre-made system for ambient backlighting? Some are white only, but many are RGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't mix and match 3528 strips/connectors with 5050 strips/connectors.

Even within  5050, RGB vs RGBW use different connectors, and there are even W-only strips in the 5050 form factor, which use a different connector still.

Put more of an effort into shopping, and you should be able to find the right items more easily.  EBay/AliExpress are not necessarily the best places to shop.